# Aligning the top of three tables in minipages

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, minipage

Can anyone tell me why I am not able to align the top of these 3 Tables? I have tried to go through the questions, but nothing helps.

I hope you can help me!

```
\begin{table}[H]
     \begin{minipage}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{|p{2,3cm}|p{1,3cm}|} \hline 
        \rowcolor{Blue} \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textcolor{White}{Labour Cost}}                         \\ \hline
        Shifts                   & 2,5          \\ \hline
        Operators                & 4            \\ \hline
        Salary (hour)            & 21.8      \\
        Overtime                 & 30\%         \\ \hline
        Hours with normal salary & 10,4         \\ \hline
        Average salary           & 24.9      \\ \hline
        Salary per day           & 1,995   \\ \hline
        \rowcolor{Blue} 300 days of salary       & 598,541 \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{My caption}
        \label{tab:labourcost}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{2,3cm}|p{1,4cm}|} \hline 
        \rowcolor{Blue} \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textcolor{White}{E-Coating Cost}}                         \\ \hline
        Average run time/day    & 20 Hours         \\ \hline
        Oven start time   & 2 Hours            \\ \hline
        Cost per kWh            &  0,16       \\
        Oven energy consumption/hour  & 950 kW         \\ \hline
        Other energy consumption/hour & 176,5 kW         \\ \hline
        Cost per hour    &  180,2      \\ \hline
        Cost per day           &  3,965.3   \\ \hline
        \rowcolor{Blue} 300 days of salary       &  1,189,584 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{tab:ecoatcost}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{2,3cm}|p{1,2cm}|} \hline 
        \rowcolor{Blue} \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textcolor{White}{Labour Cost}}                         \\ \hline
        Shifts                   & 2,5          \\ \hline
        Operators                & 4            \\ \hline
        Salary (hour)            & 21.8      \\
        Overtime                 & 30\%         \\ \hline
        Hours with normal salary & 10,4         \\ \hline
        Average salary           & 24.9      \\ \hline
        \rowcolor{GKNBlue} 300 days of salary       & 598,541 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{tab:chaincost}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

Thank you

Comment: you are top aliging the minipages but the top thing in each is a vertically centred tabular, you probably want `\begin{tabular}[t]`

Answer (score 2):

You are top aligning the minipages but the top thing in each is a vertically centred tabular, you probably want

```
\begin{tabular}[t]
```